# Sorting a combined list of numbers and letters in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting

I am trying to sort a list in Python, but one containing both letters and numbers in the same term. The problem with using sort on a string is that it doesn't sort the numbers correctly:

```
2
23
3
```

etc

```
list = [("a", ['8', '0']), ("a", ['7', '0b']), ("a", ['7', '0']), ("a", ['6', '0b']), ("a", ['6', '01']]

new_list = sorted(list, key=lambda i: i[1]) 
# works great on ints.
```

The letters need to be sorted as there number equivalent, ie:

```
a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4 etc
```

hence `4.1a` == `4.11`

But I need to preserve the letter in the output and not just convert it to an int. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the expected result for the input you have shown?

Comment: Write a function that converts `i[1]` to string, replaces `a` with `1`, `b` with `2` etc in the string, then returns the string converted to float, and use that as the `key`?

Comment: The above sounds perfect.  Will try and figure out how to do that (I'm new to advanced python).

Comment: Can you guarantee that letters greater than `i` will never be present in the data? Otherwise, what happens to letters greater than `i`? Eg, does `j` get treated as 0 or as 10?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
def f(s):
    m = {'a': 1,'b': 2,'c': 3,'d': 4,'e': 5,
         'f': 6,'g': 7,'h': 8,'i': 9,'j': 10,
         'k': 11,'l': 12,'m': 13,'n': 14,'o': 15,
         'p': 16,'q': 17,'r': 18,'s': 19,
         't': 20,'u': 21,'v': 22,'w': 23,
         'x': 24,'y': 25,'z': 26}
    result = []
    for l in s:
        try:
            result.append(int(l))
        except ValueError:
            result.append(m[l])
    return result

list = [("a", ['8', '0']), ("a", ['7', '0b']), ("a", ['7', '0']), ("a", ['6', '0b']), ("a", ['6', '01'])]
new_list = sorted(list, key=lambda i: f(''.join(i[1])))

>>> new_list
[('a', ['6', '01']),
 ('a', ['6', '0b']),
 ('a', ['7', '0']),
 ('a', ['7', '0b']),
 ('a', ['8', '0'])]
```

The function converts something like '60b' to [6,0,2] (the letters are converted to integers following the mapping dict. Then lambda sorts based on the returned list.

Comment: I suspect the OP wants `['7', '0']` to appear before `['6', '01']` in the sorted order.

Comment: @PM2Ring I don't think so, `['7','0']` should mean version 7.0, that goes after version 6.01. In case you are right though, it's enough to change `f(''.join(i[1]))` to `f(i[1][1])` in the lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear from your question, but I assume that you are ignoring the first item in each tuple, and only sorting on the list in the second item. I also assume that *only* letters from 'a' to 'i' can occur in in that list.

A simple way to convert a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, ... i -> 9 is to take advantage of the fact that the ASCII codes of the digit characters are contiguous and so are the lower case letters. Thus there's a constant offset of 48 between each letter and its equivalent digit.

So to convert a list of strings to a key we can join all the strings into a single string, then convert each letter char in the string into its equivalent digit char, join the resulting chars back into a single string, and convert that string to an integer.

```
lst = [
    ("a", ['8', '0']), 
    ("a", ['7', '0b']), 
    ("a", ['7', '0']), 
    ("a", ['6', '0b']), 
    ("a", ['6', '01']),
]

def keyfunc(t):
    a = [chr(ord(c) - 48) if 'a' <= c <= 'i' else c for c in ''.join(t[1])]
    return int(''.join(a))

new_lst = sorted(lst, key=keyfunc)
for row in new_lst:
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
('a', ['7', '0'])
('a', ['8', '0'])
('a', ['6', '01'])
('a', ['6', '0b'])
('a', ['7', '0b'])
```

BTW, you should not use `list` as a variable name, as that shadows the built-in `list` type, and that can lead to mysterious bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing an incremental sort or are you only sorting by the `a1`elements?

If you really need to get a number value for a letter, you can probably use 
`string.ascii_letters.index(letter)`
Or even better, if you only need consecutive numbers for letters, a<=b, 
use `ord(letter)`.

But I think letters should sort properly without needing to get an integer value. I think the problem is splitting `['a', 'a1']`.

I'm not sure if this is what you need:

```
def sort_func(item):
    try:
        return item[1][1][1]
    except:
        return item[1][1]

# sort by the alphanumeric
vals.sort(key=sort_func)
# sort again by the number
vals.sort(key=lambda i: int(i[1][0]))
# sort again by the first letter
vals.sort(key=lambda i:i[0])
```